# Active directory on mac server

Tags: mac-osx-server

Can an apple server run Active directory instead of open directory or Active directory is just an addon feature for the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently Snow Leopard Server cannot run active directory server, unless you run windows server in a VM on it.

you can however use the old PDC method however this wont work out of the box with windows 7 clients and it will provide some basic windows logon functionality, however the server has to be an open directory master or connected to one in some way

the server can only bind to an active directory network to integrate mac client management in an AD network and obtain authentication info from the AD servers it cant be the AD master

for more info try [here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=ServerAdmin/10.6/en/od49108701.html) or [here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=ServerAdmin/10.6/en/od4927a919.html)